# JS Module pattern

Tags: javascript

I try to understand the use of Module design pattern in JS. My problem is that multiple calls to the following function (with the new operator) will create objects with copies of the functions `inc` and `reset`. This seems like a waste that makes this patterns useless. what am I missing?

```js
    function Counter(start) {
        let counter = 0;
        function setCounter(x) { counter = x;} // private function
        setCounter(start);

        return {
            inc: function () { return counter++;},
            reset: function () { setCounter(0); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code demonstrates the factory pattern. A *module* would be created by calling the function only once, to create a single object which then gets exported.

Comment: What exactly do you think is a waste here? Notice that every call to `Counter()` also creates a "copy" of the `counter` variable and the `setCounter` function. This is exactly what you want, is it not?

Answer (score 0):

While you have multiple `inc` and `reset` functions, they operate on different `counter` variables so are not copies.

```js
function counter(start) {
  let counter = 0;

  function setCounter(x) {
    counter = x;
  } // private function
  setCounter(start);

  return {
    inc: function() {
      return counter++;
    },
    reset: function() {
      setCounter(0);
    }
  }
}


const one = counter(0);
const two = counter(0);

console.log(one.inc());
console.log(one.inc());
console.log(one.inc());
console.log(one.inc());
console.log("---");
console.log(two.inc());
console.log(two.inc());
console.log("---");
console.log(one.inc());
```

Comment: So - if I create a million counters, I will duplicate the functions themselves millions of times - so it is a huge waist...

Comment: is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: The functions are not duplicated. They are unique. You sound like you are very much falling into [premature optimisation](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization) territory. If you really want to avoid it, use object orientation instead, then the functions will be inherited on the prototype.

Comment: @Quentin I think you're both saying the same thing: creating a million counters creates a million unique function objects.

Comment: @Bergi - correct - and this might be a major issue in terms of memory, right?

Comment: @Quentin - in your example, object one has its own 2 function objects - `inc` and `reset`, and so as object two - it has another 2 function objects

Comment: Try: ```console.log(one.inc === two.inc)``` - it's false

Comment: @DuduArbel No. If you can create a million counter objects and variables, you can also create a million function objects. Like Quentin said, don't prematurely optimise anything. Do you *actually* create a million instances in your application? And does it have memory issues?

Comment: This is for educational purposes. my conclusion is that if you create a lot of objects - do not use the Module pattern